# :Releasing OnClickListener()

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have the below code:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            i++;
        }
    });
```

But the problem with that is, when a user touches the view with another finger, onClickListerner() does not work again unless he releases the first touch. And I am looking for a way how to release a click immediately so that the listener can be triggered by multi touch.

I have also tried:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    i++;
                    motionEvent.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                    i++;
                    return true;
                }
                default:
                    return true;

            }
        }
    });
```

It could not release the first touch but i was able to enable multi-touch.